# Call lua function (with require 'nn') in c++

Tags: c++, lua, torch

I have a Lua function:

```
require 'nn'
require 'image'
require 'torch'
require './lib/data_augmentation'
function predict (x) do
  model = torch.load("trained.t7")
  img = image.load(x)
  img_tensor = torch.DoubleTensor(2, 3, 32, 32)
  img_tensor[1]:copy(img)
  x = data_augmentation(img_tensor[1])
  preprocessing(x,params)
  preds = torch.Tensor(4):zero()
  step = 64
  for j = 1, x:size(1), step do
     batch = torch.Tensor(step, x:size(2), x:size(3), x:size(4)):zero()
     n = step
     if j + n > x:size(1) then
        n = 1 + n - ((j + n) - x:size(1))
     end
     batch:narrow(1, 1, n):copy(x:narrow(1, j, n))
     z = model:forward(batch):float()
     for k = 1, n do
       preds = preds + z[k]
     end
  end
  preds:div(x:size(1))
  confidences, indices = torch.sort(preds,true)
  return indices[1]
end
end
```

I want to call this function in C++, but I am getting an error:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)
```

because of the require '...'

What should I do, so that C++ can recognize all the packages or other Lua scripts (like data_augmentation)?

Comment: You need to call something like [`luaL_dofile`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_dofile) on all of the library components.

Comment: I understand how to do that for the scripts that I created like the data_augmentation. But for 'nn', 'optim', 'image' and 'torch', what should I write? I assume that I have to give the path towards the packages with my compile command, right? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need load `package` library before execute this script. So create new Lua stet, open at least `base` and `package` library. May be better open all standart libraries.

Comment: Looking for an answer, I realized that I have to use:   luaL_requiref(L,"nn",luaopen_nn,1); after luaL_openlibs();. The problem is that I should include the path to package "nn" in the compile command. I am using -l:nn.so.1 but it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on my mac and solved it with

```
source ~/.profile
```

then running lua script.

Full instructions found here: [torch.ch](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_)

```
# On Linux with bash
source ~/.bashrc
# On Linux with zsh
source ~/.zshrc
# On OSX or in Linux with none of the above.
source ~/.profile
```